# Is this correct for derivative of $\frac 1 {x+2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I don't believe this is correct answer as is not given in list of possible answers for question. This question to find derivative for $\frac 1 {x+2}$  is contained in single variable calculus course I'm taking.

Here is my attempt :

## $$\frac {df} {dx} = \frac 1 {x+2}$$

## $$\Big( \frac 1 {x+2}\Big)^1$$

## $$\Big( (1)( \frac 1 {x+2}\Big)^{1-1}$$

## $$\Big( \frac 1 {x+2}\Big)^{0}$$

$$1$$

I've made an error in steps to arrive at 1 ?

Comment: Have you learned the quotient rule? Or the chain rule?

Comment: The error you made is that you applied a "power rule" when you didn't need to and, if you do use the power rule, you didn't follow it by using the chain rule.

Comment: You should realize that this is wrong because you could do the same thing with *any* function to arrive at $df/dx = 0$ for all functions $f$.

Comment: That's a hoot!  Given any function f(x), you can write it as $(f(x))^1$ and conclude that the derivative is 1.  You have forgotten the "chain rule".  After having used the "power rule" you have to multiply by the derivative of f(x).  Of course, that means that there really was no point in writing it as $(f(x))^1$ in the first place!

Comment: What you actually calculated was $\frac{df}{d(\frac{1}{x+2})}$ or $\frac{df}{df}$

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=(x+2)^{-1}$$

Using chain rule,

\begin{align}\frac{df(x)}{dx} &= (-1)(x+2)^{-1-1}\frac{d}{dx}(x+2) \\&= -(x+2)^{-2}\frac{d}{dx}(x+2) \\ &= -\frac{1}{(x+2)^2} \frac{d}{dx}(x+2) \end{align}

Can you complete the last part?

Answer (score 3):

You neglected the quotient rule or its simple case that is the reciprocal rule. What you did would be correct if you went on from there to apply the chain rule, but that would leave you where you started.

One may write
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx}\, \frac 1 {x+2} = \frac d {dx} (x+2)^{-1} & = (-1)(x+2)^{-1-1} \cdot \underbrace{\frac d {dx} (x+2)} \\[15pt]
& = -(x+2)^{-2} \cdot 1 = \frac{-1}{(x+2)^2}
\end{align}
The part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ is there because of the chain rule.

What you did would be correct if you used the chain rule, thus
\begin{align}
\frac d {dx}\, \left( \frac 1 {x+2} \right)^1 = 1\left( \frac 1 {x+2} \right)^{1-1} \cdot \underbrace{\frac d {dx} \, \frac 1 {x+2}}_\text{chain rule} = 1 \cdot \frac d {dx}\left( \frac 1 {x+2} \right).
\end{align}
But that only gets you back to where you started. (But it's correct.)

The reciprocal rule says $\displaystyle\frac d {dx}\, \frac 1 {f(x)} = \frac{-f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}.$ If you apply that with $f(x)=x+2,$ you'll get the right answer.

The most usual way of proving that $\displaystyle \frac d {dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ works for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ but not for $n=-1,-2,-3,\ldots.$ However, one can prove it works when $n=-1,-2,-3,\ldots$ by writing things like this:
$$
\frac d{dx} x^{-6} = \frac d {dx} \, \frac 1 {x^6} = \cdots
$$
and then apply the reciprocal rule and then simplify.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done by using power rule is that  you have differentiated $\frac{1}{x+2}$ w.r.t. $\frac{1}{x+2}$, Which essentially gave you 1.  You have to apply chain rule since you want to differentiate 
 $\frac{1}{x+2}$  w.r.t. $x$.